# Prove that $\mu(x,z)\geq \min \left \{ \mu(x,y),\mu(y,z) \right \}$ for $x,y,z\in \{ 0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $x,y,z\in M:=\{ 0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and define $\mu(x,y)=\min\{ n\in \mathbb{N}\mid x_{n}\neq  y_{n}\}$.

I want to show that $\mu(x,z)\geq \min \left \{ \mu(x,y),\mu(y,z) \right \}$.

I have tested that it is true if I, for example, let $n=3$. Now I want to prove it generally. If I assume that $x=y=z$ then it is clearly satisfied. Assuming $x\neq y\neq z$ seems challenging to me. Since $\min \left \{ \cdot,\cdot \right \}$ has only one value then I can assume without loss of generality that $\min \left \{ \mu(x,y),\mu(y,z) \right \}=\mu(x,y)$. I am thinking about proving it by contradiction that $\mu(x,z)<\mu(x,y)$ for all $x,y,z\in M$ but I am unsure about it.

Comment: Does $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ denote binary vectors?

Comment: @echo Sorry, it denotes the set of bit sequences. I don't know if it's same as binary vectors.

Comment: Please check my answer. Is it what you want?

Comment: Do not delete this thread as well, as you did with the two other threads, in which you asked questions about the same problem (which, evidently, seems to be some sort of assignment that you want us to do for you), because if somebody else stumbles upon a similar problem, they might find this thread.

Comment: @Jaood, I won't this time. The other threads were something I haven't been happy with. I have found the similar proof technique I needed. Good night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your notations correctly, $\mu(x,y)$ denotes the smallest $i$ such that $x_i \neq y_i$. **Correct me if I'm wrong.**

Let $\mu(x,y)=i$ and $\mu(y,z)=j$, we have then
$$
x_k = y_k, \forall 1 \leq k < i \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
y_k = z_k, \forall 1 \leq k < j \tag{2}
$$
Without loss of generality, assume $i > j$. We will have, according to (1) and (2),
$$
x_k = z_k, \forall 1 \leq k < j
$$
Thus
$$
\mu(x, z) \geq j = \min\{\mu(x,y), \mu(y,z)\}
$$